# Erroneous element error with mapstruct and OpenAPI

Tags: java, mapstruct, openapi-generator

While trying to convert the java model generated by openapi-generator with MapStruct getting the following exception

> error: No implementation was created for EmployeeMapper due to having
> a problem in the erroneous element
> org.openapitools.jackson.nullable.JsonNullable. Hint: this often means
> that some other annotation processor was supposed to process the
> erroneous element. You can also enable MapStruct verbose mode by
> setting -Amapstruct.verbose=true as a compilation argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the generated java files having the unused import

```
org.openapitools.jackson.nullable.JsonNullable
```

So while generating the code using openapi-generator passed the following config to ignore the JsonNullable import.

```
"openApiNullable": false
```